# Easy problem on 'The theorem on area' chapter

Tags: geometry

> $ABCD$ is a parallelogram .P is a point on $BC$ such that $BP:PC=1:2$. $DP$ produced meets $AB$ produced at $Q$. Given area of triangle $CPQ =20 \text{ cm}^2$,calculate :

$(i)$ area of triangle CDP.

$(ii)$ area of parallelogram ABCD.

I need full solution.I have no idea about the theorem on area.I just started the chapter.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Let's call, $h$ the height of $\Delta CPQ$ and $H$ the height of $\Delta CDP$. Once $\Delta CPQ$ and $\Delta CDP$ have the same base then:

$$\frac{\text{Area}(\Delta CPQ)}{\text{Area}(\Delta CDP)}=\frac{h}{H}\to \text{Area}(\Delta CDP)=20\cdot\frac{H}{h}$$

But $\Delta BQP$ and $\Delta AQD$ are similars, so

$$\frac{H+h}{h}=\frac{3x}{x}\to \frac{H}{h}=2$$

and then $$\text{Area}(\Delta CDP)=20\cdot 2=40$$

Now for the area of $ABCD$ we have 
$$\text{Area}(ABCD)=H\cdot3x$$

but $$\text{Area}(\Delta CDP)=40=\frac{H\cdot 2x}{2}\to H\cdot x=40$$

and then

$$\text{Area}(ABCD)=H\cdot3x=3\cdot 40=120$$

Comment: @Sufaid Saleel: Is it clear?

Answer (score 0):

PC/PB=PD/PQ=1/2  and angles DPC+CPQ=180 so (DPC)/(CPQ)=(DP*PC)/(PQ*PC)=PD/PQ=1/2
so (DPC)=40 
d(Q,DC)=d(B,DC) so (DBC)=(DQC)

Comment: there  are also other similar ways using the thales theorem

Comment: how you wrote PC/PB=PD/PQ??

Comment: thats the thales theorem